# node nx env vars work with serve not build

Tags: node.js, typescript, monorepo, nx.dev

I'm assuming there's something simple I'm missing because I'm new to this tool.

I'm using `"nx": "14.8.2",`

I have `apps/api/.env` with `NX_API_PORT=5000`

This works when I use the `api:serve` command, but run the built code from a dev build to test it with `node dist/apps/api/main.js` the api port is undefined and my `|| fallbackPort` is used.

I tried some of the other `.env` file naming patterns from their [docs](https://nx.dev/recipes/environment-variables/define-environment-variables) but no luck.

I would rather use the `environment.ts` files from `apps/app-name/src/environments`, but I have a `libs/shared/api/data-access` lib that exports methods to call my `apps/api`, so this lib needs the `apps/api` env vars to build the base url differently between dev and prod.